# 530 Login Incorrect when Downloading File

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Using the same connection, there was no problem to get in and get a directory listing.

[image: Status log when logging into FTP server and retrieving a directory list]

The directory listing showed up without any issue and I got logged in properly.

However, when I try to download a file, re-authentication is required and the authentication failed for some reason.

[image: 530 Login incorrect when attempting to download a file]

Any idea why this is happening?

I've tried rebooting my PC, changing the password to an incorrect one and then back to the correct password as well as creating a new connection profile with no change in behavior.

Currently trying to delete FileZilla and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your server does not allow you to login multiple times using the same account.

Test that by trying to open another connection in a second tab in FileZilla. If that fails with the same error (530), it's clearly the problem.

You cannot use FileZilla to transfer files to/from a server, that does not allow parallel connections.

You have to use another FTP client that is able to use the main connection for file transfers.

For example [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/) does that. [WinSCP can also import FileZilla sites](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_import), so a transition should be smooth.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*